# KeePass Quandary with windows 8.1

Tags: keepass

I am trying to use KeePass as a password manager. I am trying to create a great secure password for my email. But that email is linked to my microsoft account which forces me to use that password for my system login. Is there a way to get around writing down and typing a long encrypted password every time I boot my machine?

Comment: You can use a fingerprint to authenicate instead, or not link your account to a Microsoft account, or use a smart card if you have access to one, but if none of those are acceptable pick a shorter password and use 2-factor authenication instead

Comment: @Ramhound Do I delete this question because I feel foolish now... I'll go w/ not linking my Mic. account... uugghh,.. thanks for the help... last question, if you are familiar w/ keepass, do I need keepasshttp to use link keypass w/ chromeIpass? or am I a victim of social engineering?